# Cocoa pods framework not picking up the files

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

I'm working on a project using SwiftyJson and Alamofire at the moment, including these two framework manually by myself and it works fine .But after I trying to switch it by using cocoa pods ,everything breaks.It shows lots of errors says my working copy is missing.Does anyone has same problem before ? Thanks!

[After I do pod install it looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aJ9w8.png)

[Some of the missing copy shows like this..](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tNvvs.jpg)

Comment: show the error it is esasy to solve

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions , Anbu,Karthik. I've edited it with images with error ,cloud you have a look ,please? Thanks!